# linux-xampp-mysql : Mysql database won't start

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, lampp

I have installed XAMPP-5.6.3-0 in my Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit machine.
Now **Mysql Database** is not running.

When I'm trying to open **`phpmyadmin`** the following error is shown :

Welcome to phpMyAdmin

Error

MySQL said: Documentation

## 2002 - No such file or directory

The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

**The following snapshots might help:**
[image: phpMyadmin Error]
[image: Xampp GUI]

All the web pages stored inside /opt/lampp/htdocs are accessed properly.

The contents of **my.cnf** are [Mysql Configuration](http://hastebin.com/ikunipojad.vala)

Answer (score 0):

try to Open the php.ini file and find this line:

```
mysql.default_socket
```

And change it to

```
mysql.default_socket = /path/to/mysql.sock
```

try to sit path to /var/run/mysqld

```
mysql.default_socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock
```

Comment: This is the part of the code [http://hastebin.com/asiketaxul.pas] . Can you help me a bit with what the update code should be ? I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: search about [mysql.default_socket] not [pdo_mysql.default_socket]

Comment: I have two files php.ini and php.ini-pre1.7.2. Both contains `mysql.default_socket=' line. I'm changing the this to the path suggested by you `mysql.default_socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock`. Still no luck

Comment: did you restart the apache server?

Comment: Yes I restarted all the services.

Comment: This is the my.cnf file [http://hastebin.com/ixubataqik.vala] which gets opened when I click the configure option in GUI of Xampp , which also contains a field for the socket. And this is the updated file [http://hastebin.com/xitukabaqo.vhdl]. Any suggestions?